# Run CCAction on multiple sprites

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have an array of sprites and run an action on each element. the issue I am having is that the last sprite is the only one that moves.

If I add 3 arrays and iterate through each and use the following

```
CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:moveSequence];
    [[row1 objectAtIndex:i] runAction:repeat];
```

it only move the last drawn sprite.

How does one run an action on every element in an Array?

I need the objects to move at the same time. So all sprites should run the action simultaneously. Is this possible with cocos2d

EDIT*********************************

```
- (void) moveAliens
{
    id left = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:10 position:ccp(-35, 0)];
    id right = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:10 position:ccp(35, 0)];
    id moveSequence = [CCSequence actions:left, [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:20],     right, [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:20], nil];
    id repeatMoveSequence = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:moveSequence];

for (int i = 0; i < [row1 count]; i++) 
{
    NSLog(@"i is %d", i);
    //CCRepeatForever *repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:moveSequence];
    [[row1 objectAtIndex:i] runAction:repeatMoveSequence];
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your loop code and maybe how you setup your arrays?  Also, any reason you don't loop through your arrays by the *sprite instead of objectatindex?

Comment: I added my code, thanks. please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place:

```
left = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:10 position:ccp(-35, 0)];
right = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:10 position:ccp(35, 0)];
moveSequence = [CCSequence actions:left, [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:20],     right, [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:20], nil];
repeatMoveSequence = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:moveSequence];
```

inside your for loop. And the variable declarations above it.

You can't use one CCAction for multiple CCNodes simultaneously.